# Non-Constant Acceleration

Tags: physics

How do we calculate time that we need for specific distance if we have non-constant acceleration.
I have some formulas for other variable but don't have for time:

Speed at time:
$$
v(t) = v_0+at+\frac{j(t^2)}{3}
$$

Distance at time:
$$
x(t)=x_0+v_0t+\frac{a(t^2)}{2}+\frac{j(t^3)}{6}
$$

Acceleration at time:
$$
a(t)=a_0+jt
$$

Comment: You need to solve $x(t) = L$. As it is a polynomial of degree 3, you'll need Cardano's method (or an equivalent method) to get an explicit solution.

Comment: If $j$ is *constant* speed of acceleration change, $x(t)=x_0+v_0t+{a_0t^2 \over 2} + {jt^3 \over 6}$, where $x_0, v_0, a_0$ are coordinate, speed and acceleration at $t=0$. Do you have exactly this situation (i.e. for $t>0$ you move with constant speed of acceleration increase)?

Comment: I don't know if I understand you question. But yes j (jerk) is constant in my case and $v_0$ is not 0 at t=0 also $v_0$ is not 0 at t=0; I found very helpful Cardano's method mentioned in comment above and answer belowe for cubie equation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have there is a cubic equation,  so if you want to solve for a specific distance, you would take your formula for $x(t)$,  subtract the specific distance you want to get a cubic equaling 0, and then you would use the cubic formula, one version of which is posted here: http://www.math.vanderbilt.edu/~schectex/courses/cubic/

Warning, its not pretty.